# Extract PDF labels to a CSV file using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, csv, pdf

I would like to extract the page labels of a PDF into a CSV file, however at the moment what I have is only a for loop that shows the labels in the Adobe Acrobat javascript console.

The code is:

```
var labels = this.getPageLabel(0);
for (var i=1; i<this.numPages; i++)
    labels += ", " + this.getPageLabel(i);
    console.println(labels);
```

Is there a way to export the results from the console to a csv file or another method that would create a csv file with the expected results? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sure, this is possible.

You would create a Data Object, and then export it. The contents of that Data Object is your labels string. For syntax and additional information, see Acrobat JavaScript documentation.